# How can I achieve a somewhat similar graph?

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

[image: Pie Chart]

How can I achieve a similar graph? I am using [victory-native](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native/).
Expo Link: https://snack.expo.io/@sushil62/animated-pie-chart

Answer (score 1):

You can set the similar pie charts by using the padAngle and innerRadius props to Victory pie like

```
<VictoryPie
  padAngle={5}
  innerRadius={50}
  data={sampleData}
/>
```

and regarding the lines between slices and labels

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/issues/363

as discussed in this issue victory does not have such functionality as the time instead you can use legend box or tooltips to show the pie values of each pie.